# How to pass arguments in kubernetes to start a rq-worker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm working on a microservice architectural project in which I use rq-workers. I have used docker-compose file to start and connect the rq-worker with redis successfully but I'm not sure how to replicate it in kubernetes. No matter whatever I try with **command** and **args**, I'm thrown a status of **Crashloopbackoff**. Please guide me as to what I'm missing.Below are my docker-compose and rq-worker deployment files.

rq-worker and redis container config:

```
...
  rq-worker:
    build: ./simba-app
    command: rq worker --url redis://redis:6379 queue
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
    - sharedvolume:/simba-app/app/docs

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/data
...
```

rq-worker.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rq-worker
  labels:
    app: rq-worker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rq-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rq-worker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rq-worker
        image: some-image
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        #command: ["rqworker", "--url", "redis://redis:6379", "queue"]
        args:
          - rqworker
          - --url
          - redis://redis:6379
          - queue   
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I checked the logs using kubectl logs  and found the following logs:

```
Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

First of all, I'm using the 'service name' and not 'localhost' in my code to connect rq and redis. No idea why I'm seeing 'localhost' in my logs.
(Note: The kubernetes service name for redis is same as that used in my docker-compose file)

redis-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:4.0.6-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
   - port: 6379
     targetPort: 6379
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `/bin/sh -c` wrapper here.  Your setup reads the first `args:` word, `rqworker`, and parses it as a shell command, and executes it; the remaining words are lost.

The most straightforward thing to do is to make your command, split into words as-is, as the Kubernetes `command:`

```yaml
      containers:
      - name: rq-worker
        image: some-image
        command:
          - rqworker
          - --url
          - redis://redis:6379
          - queue
```

(This matches the commented-out string in your example.)

A common Docker pattern is to use an `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time setup and to make `CMD` be a complete shell command that's run at the end of the setup script.  In Kubernetes, `command:` overrides Docker `ENTRYPOINT`; if your image has this pattern, then you need to not use a `command:`, but instead to put this command as you have it as `args:`.

The only time you do need an `sh -c` wrapper is in unusual cases where you need to run multiple commands, expand environment variables, or otherwise use shell-only features.  In this case the command itself must be in a *single* word in the `command:` or `args:`.

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - rqworker --url redis://redis:6379 queue
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidMaze for your detailed explanation and help. Really appreciate it! Finally got it working.